# Dynamic input fields and display info

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hello I don't have much knowledge in jQuery maybe someone could take a look, here it is:

```
jQuery(function($) {
  $('#precoInserido').bind('keydown keyup keypress', function() {
    $('#precoVer').html(this.value || "??");
  });
});
```

[jsfiddle.net/5LrQk/1/](http://jsfiddle.net/5LrQk/1/)

Basically the problem is I have to make the value show up automatically in the page, the price appears if you fill the input field of the price, but then I need to make some changes to where it says "You receive from each sale", it should show the value of the price of the product - 1,00€ - 1% of the full price of product. Then I need the part that says after "and for each affiliate" to show the result of the original value minus the value of the commission that is inserted in the input field of the commission. Sorry for my English.

Comment: Links to JSFiddle must be accompanied by code. Indenting the link in a code block doesn't make it code.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you meant with "the before value" so the affiliate price math is not included. I'm sure you can figure it out by yourself.

```
// we want the values to update on keypress on either input field,
// thus we use input[type=text] as our selector.
$('input[type=text]').bind('keydown keyup keypress', function () {
    // we save the price and commission to variables for easy access
    // we also make sure they're numbers instead of strings with parseFloat()
    var price = parseFloat($("#precoInserido").val());
    var commission = parseFloat($("#comission").val());

    $('#precoVer').html(price);
    // we calculate and insert the sale profit
    $("#sale").html( ( (price - 1) * 0.01).toFixed(2) );
    // we calculate and insert the commission
    $("#affiliate").html(); // put your math here
});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5LrQk/6/)

Answer (score 0):

Check this **[Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5LrQk/9/)**

HTML changes :

```
<br />Your product costs € <span id='precoVer'>??</span>. 
You receive from each sale €<span id='precoVer1'>??</span> 
and for each affiliate <span id='diff'>??</span> € .
```

---

JS changes :

```
jQuery(function ($) {

    $('#precoInserido').bind('keydown keyup keypress', function () {
        $('#precoVer').html(this.value || "??");
        $('#precoVer1').html(parseInt(this.value).toFixed(2) || "??");
        $('#diff').html(parseInt(this.value) - parseInt($('#comission').val()));
    });

    $('#comission').bind('keydown keyup keypress', function () {

        $('#diff').html(parseInt($('#precoInserido').val()) - parseInt(this.value));
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

to be honest, I'm not entirely sure what you have in mind in terms of the math that generates the affiliate pricing, but I took a stab at what I "think" you need.

http://jsfiddle.net/5LrQk/14/

```
jQuery(function($) {

  $('#precoInserido').bind('keydown keyup keypress', function() {
    $('#precoVer, #uservalue').html(this.value || "??");
    $('#comission').trigger('keydown');
  });
  $('#comission').bind('keydown keyup keypress', function() {
    $('#affiliatevalue').html(this.value || "??");
      var currVal = this.value;
      var fullPrice =  $('#precoInserido').val() || false;
      if( fullPrice ){

          $('#uservalue').html(function(){
              var uv = parseInt( ( fullPrice - 1 ) ) - ( fullPrice / 10 );
              $('#affiliatevalue').html(function(){
                 return ( ( uv * ( currVal / 100 ) ).toFixed(2) );
              });
              return uv;
          });
      }

  });

});
```

your HTML:

```
  <script class="jsbin" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Charge from the house: 1,00€ - 1% full price<br /><br />

Price: <input id='precoInserido' type="text"  name="preco"  /><br />
Comission Affiliate: <input id='comission' type="text"  name="comission"  /><br />
Your product costs € <span id='precoVer'>0</span>. You receive from each sale <span id='uservalue'>0</span> € and for each affiliate <span id='affiliatevalue'>0</span>€ .
```

Answer (score 0):

You would need to wrap the values you want to change in `<span>` tags, target them by class or id, compute the value you want to change in the event handler, and then change the value.

```
<div>
    Charge from the house: 1,00€ - 1% full price
    <br /><br />
    Price: <input id='precoInserido' type="text"  name="preco"  />
    <br />
    Comission Affiliate: <input id='comission' type="text"  name="comission"  />
    <br />
    Your product costs € <span id='precoVer'>??</span>.
    You receive from each sale <span id='saleCommission'>???</span>€
    and for each affiliate <span id='affiliateCommission>???</span>€.
</div>
```

The logic to handle this would be something like this:

```
$('#precoInserido').bind('keydown keyup keypress', function() {
    var price = $('#precoVer').val();
    var saleCommission;      // = your math, rounding, and formatting here
    var affiliateCommission; // = your math, rounding, and formatting here
    $('#precoVer').html(this.value || "??");
    $('#saleCommission').html(saleCommission || "??");
    $('#affiliateCommission').html(affiliateCommission || "??");
});
```

That being said, there are a few things you could do to clean this up.

- [.bind()](http://api.jquery.com/bind/) should be replaced with [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/). While it hasn't been deprecated, it is no longer the preferred way to attach event handlers.
- In this instance, when changing the value of `#precoVer` and company, you would be better off using [.text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/) instead of [.html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/), since you are altering content, rather than layout.
- Try assigning a default value to the variable, instead of within the DOM manipulation. The [ternary conditional operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) is good for this.
- I suspect that you don't have the finer points of key events down. This is a good read, to understand the distinction between them. http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/keys.html
- Consider using `<p>` tags instead of `<br />` in this instance. They'll give you the spacing that you're looking for.